# Add all edit-related privileges to the /privileges page

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, privileges, privileges-page

According to [the suggested edit FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), there are a number of reputation levels that are important for suggested edits.

1. 1-1999 rep (anonymous user): suggest edits for any post more than ten minutes old
2. 1-1999 (registered user): suggest edits for any post or tag wiki
3. 2000: review suggested edits for posts
4. 2000: edit posts without peer review
5. 5000: review suggested edits for tag wikis
6. 10,000: see the "suggested edits" tab in the review/tools page; receive notifications about pending edits
7. 20,000: edit tag wikis without peer review

Right now, only items 4, 5 and 7 are mentioned on the `/privileges` page. I propose adding the rest.

Comment: I think it's more a bug than feature request, the privileges page should reflect these recent changes.